# Attribute Error: 'TrainType' object has no attribute 'v'; attribute should have an external access to class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started learning Python while ago and joined SO, now here's my first attempt to classes. I've met a problem which I cannot solve for a longer while and get error:

> AttributeError: 'TrainType' object has no attribute 'v'

Here is the code:

```
import math

class TrainType(object):
    def __init__(self,t,M,n,L,S,pas):
        self.t = t              # train model
        self.M = M              # train mass [t]
        self.n = n              # numer of axles [-]
        self.L = L              # train length [m]
        self.S = S              # crossection area [m2]
        self.pas = pas          # passenger capacity [-]

# Running resistance force formula
def run_res(self,v):
    C = 0.0035*self.S+0.041*self.L/100+0.002;
    R_L = 9.81*(1.3*math.sqrt(10*self.n/self.M)+0.01*self.v)*self.M+C*v**2
    return R_L

# Power required formula
def power(self,v):
    a = self.run_res(v)
    P = a*v
    return P

train1 = TrainType("Talgo 350",323,21,200,10,318)

print(train1.run_res(10))       # for test reasons v = 10
print(train1.power(10))
```

**v** is an external variable which is an argument in `class TrainType` methods.

I've search through SO, found few threads where the solution was related to global variables, so I've tried to solve it via `global v` or with `globals()['v']` but it doesn't help:

> SyntaxError: name 'v' is parameter and global.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `self.v`? Why the `self.`?

Comment: Search through my code again and I haven't put anywhere `self.v` as it is an external parameter, only `(self,v)` to set the function arguments. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Ctrl-F `self.v`. You'll find it does appear in your code.

Comment: Sorry, it's late, you're right, thanks for help!